# LLDB Expression Evaluation: insertion operator (<<) gets interpreted as template

Tags: debugging, llvm, lldb

I'm debugging a program with LLDB and I'm trying to evaluate at runtime: "errs() << loadInstr". However LLDB shows an eval error:

```
> expr errs() << loadInstr
expr errs() << loadInstr
error: template parameter lists have a different number of parameters (1 vs 2)
```

It would appear that LLDB interprets the << as a template expression, not as the insertion operator (<<). Putting the same code in the .cpp file works corectly.

I've tried:

- Parenthesis (doesn't work)
- errs()->operator<<() : fails with different error
- Writing a helper function that I can call instead of operator << - this works but it's not exactly what I want.

Comment: What kind of thing is errs?  The expression parser can tell the difference between <<  and a template declaration in other cases, and it can parse simple << expressions correctly.  Maybe the problem is there's a templated << operator and it's getting that wrong?  I need a more complete example to see what's wrong.

Comment: I am debugging LLVM. errs() is a function returning a raw_ostream.
The source code can be found at [raw_ostream.cpp](http://llvm.org/doxygen/raw__ostream_8cpp_source.html)  :: 768

Comment: llvm::raw_ostream gets used in a bunch of places in lldb.  I just tried calling "<<" on some places where we have a raw_ostream.  I had to be careful about casting the input in a couple of cases, but the parser could handle the call.  What is loadInstr?  Maybe it has an overload that's the actual problem.

Comment: loadInstr is an instance of an LLVM [LoadInstr class](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1LoadInst.html).

Comment: Huh, still can't get it to fail the way you are seeing, sorry...  If you can make up a repro case that you're willing to give out, please file a bug at http://bugs.llvm.org.